# C++ Random Number Generator stops generating numbers at all after 2 times usually when i run the program in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hello I am relatively new to coding (in intro to computer programming) and i am supposed to write a code that generates a random number (1-3) for the purpose of choosing which table to display, and it cannot repeat. However whenever i run the program (on visual studio) it works perfect the first 2 times usually then on the third time the program just pauses and I'm left with the blinking dash that's in windows console. I'm sure I'm just missing a stupid mistake, but it's all about learning.
    I read online it is better to take `srand(time(NULL));` out of the loop and have it at the beginning of main, so that's what i did.

```
srand(time(NULL)); 


int beginGame(int playedBoard[])
{
    int randomNum;
    do
    {
        randomNum = (rand() % (3 - 1)) + 1;
        if (playedBoard[randomNum - 1] == NULL)
            return randomNum;
    } while (playedBoard[randomNum - 1] != NULL);
}
```

Comment: the code works fine, if you omit the playBoard function
you code don't generate numbers between 1 and 3 but 1 and 2
change to (rand() %3 ) + 1 to get values from 1 to 3

Comment: Cosmetics only, but I would add one to randomNum only when returning, you spare the subtractions this way...

Comment: i guess you error is in the playedBoard somewhere. try to debug or use print to figure out where the code get stuck

Comment: *"and I'm left with the blinking dash *" sounds like the program crashed. Possibly you accessed the playedBoard out of range? Debugging might help...  Without further context, all we can do here is guessing, though.

Comment: Again cosmetics: You do a double check on the same condition: `{if(condition) return;}while(!condition);`, one of these checks is obsolete, so you can either use a (pseudo) endless loop (`for(;;){if(condition)return;}` or just skip the inner check (`do{random = ...;}while(!condition); return;`); I'd rather prefer the latter.

Comment: Without a [MCVE], all we can do is guess. My guess is that the program is crashing because of accessing playedBoard out of range.

Answer (score 1):

Take the time to use a random generator with the c++11, non-deprecated library and avoid all pitfalls.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/

Here it follows an example of how to create a generator that will return ints between (m, n), both inclusive:

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>

auto int_generator(int lower_bound_inclusive =
         std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
         int upper_bound_inclusive =
         std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {

    int const lbi = lower_bound_inclusive;
    int const ubi = upper_bound_inclusive;

    static std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int>
      dist(lbi, ubi);

    return [dist, mt]() mutable { return dist(mt); };
}
```

Usage:

```
auto dice = int_generator(1, 6); //Generate a random number generator that yields numbers between 1 and 6 inclusive
dice(); //One random number
dice(); //Another random number
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the lambda function at the `return` statement?

Comment: That function returns a lambda that is a random number generator between (m, n) inclusive. Later you can use that object and call it without arguments to generate numbers in that range.

Comment: @Galik Does that reply to your question? I think you should replace your rand() by this and my advice is that you do not use rand() anymore. It is deprecated.

Comment: 1. I personally wouldn't make rd static, typical applications most likely wouldn't create too many generators, and especially not in high performance sections, so I'd rather trade the re-creation effort for the global memory usage. 2. `namespace s = std;` I don't think you gain anything by that, it is rather irritating to see `s::xyz` instead of `std::xyz` and in fact, you don't even save typing (6 characters spared, 20 added...).

Comment: @Aconcagua it is copy pasted from my own project the-cpp-abstraction-penalty. Well, yes, you are right actually, but I was not going to modify it right now :) Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: If you *are* going to modify it, I'd recommend making a template function of, so you could generate random numbers with any data type `std::uniform_int_distribution` supports... Possibly even make the distribution a template parameter (defaulting to UID), so you could generate gaussian, ... distributions as well.

Comment: I doubt this is in any way an answer to the OP's question. I too have a RYO random number interface that simplifies using std::random. It would satisfy @Aconcagua 's concerns, but this is not the place.

Comment: @JiveDadson Truth, intended do add a similar comment myself... Did not up-vote for exactly this reason. Suppose we would even have to down-vote in this respect, hesitating, though, as the intended advice actually is quite valuable. Maybe the answer should introduce with a sentence indicating "intended as comment, but too long for"?

Comment: @Aconcagua Appropriate would be a comment, in the comment section of the Question, to the effect that std::random is preferable to rand(). This "answer" is out of order. I do not like down-voting answers. I know I don't like it when I go to the trouble of answering, only to get a slap on the wrist.

Comment: @JiveDadson Agree. Solely, comments are too limited for demonstration purposes, we'd need some feature like extended comments, giving a short normal comment together with a link to the extension (maybe these could appear below the answers?). Separating the code to other sites such as coliru isn't ideal either...

Comment: @Aconcagua actually I do not agree. If a person that is not oriented enough to know that rand() is a bad idea, helping him solve the problem and improving the advice as a side effect should be a reply in itself. FWIW, the reply mitigates the problem and shows an improved way of achieving the desired effect.

Comment: @GermánDiago It is an advice, and a *good* one, but `rand`'s rather poor distribution is *not causing* the crash that apparently occurs in the user's application (*"[...] and I'm left with the blinking dash [...]"*), thus you don't address problem he/she actually asks help for. That we aren't given an [mcve] and thus cannot really help is another matter...